# Check box click not working when we put it in column which is clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I create a table and put check box in each column

```
           <table class="bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr  style="cursor:pointer"  id="tableheading" >
                    <th>Name</th>
                       <th> 1</th>
                       <th> 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td id="heading1">Sachith  sdf</td>
                           <td id="column11"> <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="checkbox11"/></td>
                           <td id="column12"> <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="checkbox12"/></td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

and i use java script to make the column clickable.When I the check box automatically get checked and unchecked.

```
                selectedIDs[1][1]="false";
                $("#column"+11).click(function() {
                    if(document.getElementById("checkbox"+11).checked){
                        $("#column"+11).removeClass('selected');
                        selectedIDs[1][1]="false";
                        document.getElementById("checkbox"+11).checked = false;
                    }else{
                        $("#column"+11).addClass('selected');
                        selectedIDs[1][1]="true";
                        document.getElementById("checkbox"+11).checked = true;
                    }
                });

                $("#column"+11).hover(
                    function(){
                        $("#column"+11).addClass('mouseover');
                    },
                    function(){
                        $("#column"+11).removeClass('mouseover');
                    }
                );
```

but now the problem is when i click on check box nothing happens.when clicking on column it check and uncheck checkbox correctly.

Comment: If you click column the checkbox is not checking?maybe the click on column is overriding the click on the checkbox?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the generated HTML instead of your JSP template?

Comment: @Pekka how can I avoid that?

Comment: @Alfredo Delgado edited actual code is big so i put snippet of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when you click on the checkbox, the default behavior will fire also the `td` click handler will fire which will revert the value set by the default behavior.

The solution is not to run the script which sets the checked value of the click has happened in the checkbox element.

You can simplify the event handler registration by using a class for the input element instead of using the id like

```js
$('#mysometable td.checkbox').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('input')) {
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function(i, checked) {
      return !checked;
    })
  }
})
```

```css
#mysometable td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="bordered" id="mysometable">
  <thead>
    <tr style="cursor:pointer" id="tableheading">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td id="heading1">Sachith sdf</td>
      <td id="column11" class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox11" />
      </td>
      <td id="column12" class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox12"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want check box to be checked while clicking on column of table.Can I do it this way?

Comment: @user2217535 whether the checkox will be disabled?

Comment: it disables and enable clicking on column but nothing happens while clicking on checkbox.

Comment: Is there any way to know which check box is clicked.I want  to save that value.

Comment: In the click handler `$(this).find('input').` will give reference to the checkbox... `$(this).find('input').val()` should give its value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89129/discussion-between-user2217535-and-arun-p-johny).